# How to cd into a folder without name created with ALT+255 in linux terminal

Tags: bash

I tried different variants to enter with cd in the directory created with ALT+255 with the terminal in linux. one of the variants is cd "\ \" but it doesn't work. I also tried ASCII but it didn't work (cd "%20"). I don't know how to access that directory, does anyone know please?

Comment: How about `cd " "` ?

Comment: Please add an output of `ls -lta`

Comment: cd " " give me error: -bash: cd:  : No such file or directory
ls -lta output: drwxrwxr-x  3 root root 4096 Dec 27 17:49 .
drwxrwxrwt 11 root root 4096 Dec 27 17:22 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Dec 27 15:56

Comment: cd * might work

Comment: Please post additional info as edit in the question. For me, please post the output of `printf "%q\n" *` - anything it prints, you can then copy and `cd`  and paste. You can also just open a window directory browser, or use `mc`, for example. `with ALT+255 with the terminal` What terminal emulator are you using?

Comment: printf "%q\n" * shows nothing, i use terminal of ubuntu 18.04, i tried "cd *" and it works but if there are other folders I get the error: -bash: cd: too many arguments

Answer (score -1):

Use * in an array

```
cd "/to/path/with/problem/folder"
arr=(*) # create an array
echo "${arr[@]}" # check problem_folder index
cd "${arr[problem_folder_index]}" # cd to problem_folder
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't want to do that. You have now done something wrong, and you probably should clean that up. We can spend hours trying to explain how to get the right directory name, with `hexdump -C` or the likes, but in the end it is not something you are going to use in the real world.

Any way, if you really still want to `cd` to it, then you should use the correct directory-name. That would be alt+255. So, `cd "alt255"` should work (where alt255 should obviously be replaced with the alt+255 sequence that you used to create).

Or, in the shell:

```
for d in * ; do
    echo -n "DIR -$d- (y/n) "
    read a
    if [ "$a" = "y" ] ; then
        cd "$d"
    fi
done
```

(not as script, but directly on the prompt).

But, instead of `cd` you should either `rm` or `mv`.

Oh, and there is no folder without name; the name just consists of a character that is not printed.